# Is it possible to create a sub-surface pond?

Tags: water-resources

Has anyone designed a pond that extends beyond its surface perimeter?

Example cross section:
[image: sub surface example]

brown - existing surface (or brought to grade)
black - designed pond
blue - capacity

Comment: where have you looked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe this negative incline portion of the pond as a "shelf". They are common and need to be self-supporting with a material that has compression and tensile strength; concrete and rebar, rock, fiberglass, etc.

There are lots of examples of this:

- covered irrigation canals
- dam water turbine intakes
- water diversion intakes
- zoo habitats
- natural shelf under waterfalls
- naturally in water caves